# Fuzzy matching only for values within same group

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I am stuck with this problem that should have a simple solution but I cannot find it.

I have two data frames:

dfA

| Company | Country Code |
| --- | --- |
| CompanyA | IT |
| CompanyB | DE |
| CompanyC | DE |
| CompanyD | SE |

dfB

| Company | Country Code |
| --- | --- |
| Company A | IT |
| Company B | DE |
| Company C | DE |
| Company D | SE |

Dataframe B contains the correct spelling of the company names so I am trying to get a match using the fuzzywuzzy library. So far I got good similarity scores but I would like to further improve them by only comparing companies with the same country code.

This is the code I have been running so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz

actual_name = []
similarity = []

for i in dfA["Company"]:
        ratio = process.extract( i, dfB["Company"], limit=1)
        actual_name.append(ratio[0][0])
        similarity.append(ratio[0][1])
        
dfA['actual_name'] = pd.Series(actual_name)
dfA['similarity'] = pd.Series(similarity)
```

How can I improve my code so that company names are compared only if for i dfA["Country Code"] == dfB["Country Code"]?

Comment: Simplest solution would be to loop over the country codes first, filter the data by country code and then perform the fuzzymatching on the filtered data sets.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. The main problem is that my coding skills are not that advanced. I have tried to write something but my code would never work. Do you have any suggestion/link I can check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a a restrictive list where to apply the process. Use `extractOne(...)` instead of `extract(...)[0]` to get only one value.

```
dfA['Company List'] = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on='Country Code', how='left') \
                        .groupby('Company_x')['Company_y'] \
                        .apply(list).values

dfA[['actual_name', 'similarity']] = \
    dfA.apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x['Company'],
                                           x['Company List']), axis=1) \
       .apply(pd.Series)
```

Output

```
>>> dfA
    Company Country Code            Company List actual_name  similarity
0  CompanyA           IT             [Company A]   Company A          94
1  CompanyB           DE  [Company B, Company C]   Company B          94
2  CompanyC           DE  [Company B, Company C]   Company C          94
3  CompanyD           SE             [Company D]   Company D          94
```

Comment: Interesting solution but I have a problem of scalability. I have hundreds of companies and cannot put them all in a list... Do you think I could re-adapt this solution somehow?

Comment: I don't know where is the problem? Do you test the solution on your real data?